# A continuous function that is constant on a fiber?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm reading Rotman's Algebraic topology and I've come across this:

> Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be an identification and, for some space $Z$, let $h: X \rightarrow Z$ be a continuous function that is constant on each fiber of $f$.

What does it mean that $h$ is constant on each fiber of $f$?

A fiber of $f$ is just a subset of $X$, so is this implying that $h(A) = z_A \in Z,$ for each $A$ fiber in $X$?

Comment: yes, where $A=f^{-1}(y)$

Comment: Technically, that $h(A)=\{z_A\}$, but yes.